# How can I display app snippet on shopify app

Tags: liquid, code-snippets, shopify-app

I am working on a Shopify app and try to make its core code inaccessible to end users. To do that I have encapsulated the code in an app snippet, which could be callable for rendering, just by using this liquid expression {% render 'shopify://apps/reviews-up/snippets/<my_snippet>/' %}.

I followed the steps in this tutorial https://shopify.dev/tutorials/add-an-app-snippet-to-your-app but it seems to be not working unfortunately.

1 - Here is an example of the app snippet:

```
<h1>Hello World !</h1>
<script>console.log("hello world!")</script>
```

Encapsulation in: 'shopify://apps/reviews-up/snippets/<my_snippet>/<id>'

2 - Usage example: (product-template.liquid)

```
<div class="app_snippet">{% render 'shopify://apps/reviews-up/snippets/<my_snippet>/<id>' %} </div>
```

After rendering:

```
<div class="app_snippet"></div>
```

After the experience, neither the html "hello world" nor the javascript one were displayed ? Do you have some clues about my issue !

Best regards,

Comment: Make sure you've enabled online store as an extension area.
https://shopify.dev/tutorials/add-a-new-app-extension

Comment: Hi @YoussefBH, Thank you for your response. I did this action and I added the snippets following this steps: myApp -> Extensions -> Online store -> add snippet. But I cant render anythings.